# Eclipse turns Japanese into garbage during refactoring

Tags: eclipse, unicode, cjk

I have several Java files that have Japanese strings in them, and are encoded in UTF-8. I use Eclipse. However, whenever Eclipse touches them in any automated way, it turns the Japanese into garbage. A good example of this is [JAWJAW](http://nlpwww.nict.go.jp/wn-ja/index.en.html), the Java Japanese WordNet interface. You can see the code on the website with Japanese characters in it. If you load the project into Eclipse, though, everything will fail because the characters are garbled (bakemoji).

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the default encoding for your project?
Future version of Eclipse (like e4) could be set by default to UTF-8, which would avoid any automatic conversion into "garbage".

See [bug 108668](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=108668) for more on that reflexion:

> No solution will be perfect. However in the long term I think the current platform specific approach is clearly inferior to a platform-independent UTF-8 default.

---

> +1 UTF-8 should be the obvious default character set for all text files, I had
>   a problem with eclipse when I was using an English Windows XP system and trying
>   to open a file in eclipse with Chinese characters, as you can imagine the
>   display is completely messed up and eclipse doesn't tell me what I need to do.
>   I had to spend time google for answers. I had to put **`-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`** in
>   `eclipse.ini` so that it behaves correctly.

---

> Making UTF-8 the default is not the right solution for the problem you were
>   having.

---

> +1 for embedding encoding in the character stream wherever we can (like XML, HTTP, some kinds of file systems). 
>   **Encoding is meta-info for the data and belongs to the data, not to a separate user-changeable setup**.

Comment: Thanks! Window->Preferences->General->Workbench, change Text File Encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The primary reason for this cause is - the unicode supported font is missing from the system fonts. So do the following things to get it done.

- Download [Arial Unicode MS font](http://ttfonts.net/font/7059_ArialUnicodeMS.htm) and put it inside `windows->fonts`
  directory in windows.
- Change the default text encoding in eclipse to UTF-8 by navigating to

  Window->Preferences->General->Workspace->Text File encoding
     ->Other->UTF-8
- set Arial Unicode MS font to the Text Font attribute by navigating to

  Window->Preferences->General->General->Appearance->colors and
     Fonts->Basic->Text Font (select it)->Edit